# Signing PDF with itext library throws error

Tags: itext, digital-signature

please help me with this, first time I use signature over pdf. I want to sign a pdf with a certificate, but it throws me the error that I put down, I am developing a desktop application in netbeans8.2 (JAVA) using itext-5.0.5. I have read something about dependencies and versions, I really have no idea how to solve this. I appreciate your help, if you can explain me step by step would be great. Thank you

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/DERObject
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance.getAppearance(PdfSignatureAppearance.java:409)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance.preClose(PdfSignatureAppearance.java:950)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance.preClose(PdfSignatureAppearance.java:897)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper.close(PdfStamper.java:192)
at clases.Metodos.firmarFactura(Metodos.java:279)
at clases.VendedorHilo.run(VendedorHilo.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERObject
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 6 more
```

Comment: Add bouncycastle dependency to your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that you don't have BouncyCastle in your CLASSPATH. The *normal answer* to your question would be:

> Check the POM file of the iText version you are using for the BouncyCastle
>   version you need. Download that BouncyCastle version, and put it into your
>   CLASSPATH.

However, for some reason you are using an ancient version of iText dating from November 2010, and the iText release didn't have a POM file in those days.

> **IMPORTANT: It is a very bad idea in the context of digital signatures!** Since 2010, the world of digital signatures has evolved, and this evolution has led to digital signature functionality that is more secure than the functionality that was available in 2010. Please inform your employer that he is asking you to create a type of signatures that is obsolete.

If your employer deliberately wants to create signatures *the old-fashioned way*, you can check the old iText repository, and search for iText 5.0.5. You will find several bouncy castle jars in the [lib directory](https://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/HEAD/tree/tags/iText_5_0_5/lib/). Download bcmail-jdk14-138.jar, bcprov-jdk14-138.jar, and bctsp-jdk14-138.jar, and put them in your CLASSPATH.

> **IMPORTANT:** due to the nature of BouncyCastle, you can expect strange exceptions if you have more than one version of BouncyCastle in your CLASSPATH. That is another reason why you might want to use a more recent version of iText.

**Note:** it's much easier if you make your project a Maven Project. In that case, it's sufficient to declare the dependency on iText (a recent version), and Maven does all the heavy lifting in your place.

Comment: Thank you very much, I download and add exactly the JAR you commented. I will take all your recommendations for future projects. This project was a task that I had to finish quickly and I was able to solve with your help. His response was very good.